# Replace part of text

Tags: xml

I have many files that contain coding similar to this:

```xml
<link linkaction="immediate" linktype="return" xlink:href="IETM://S50005#S50005-TOOL1" 
  xreftype="table">
  <prompt>Multimeter</prompt>
</link>
```

That needs to be replaced with this:

```xml
<xref itemid="S50005-TOOL1" wpid="S50005"/>
```

Need to change the tagging structure, but keep the reference info.
Is this possible with Notepad++?

Comment: Click on the ? at the top-right of the edit window to get help with formatting. When you have edited your question to include your correctly-formatted XML I should be able to help.

Comment: In my view, it appears to be updated with correct syntax

Comment: To be more clear, I am wanting to replace all "link" with "xref", but want to capture the id information from the link and include that in the xref replacements.

Comment: IMHO, XSLT transformation is best suited for the task.

Comment: Thank you for that prompt response!  It does appear to achieve the desired result.  I'm not certain how I would use this for hundreds of files?  Would be be possible to accomplish this with Notepad++, Replace?

Answer (score 1):

Here is XSLT based solution.
Notepad++ has **XML Tools** plugin for that.

To make input XML well-formed, I had to add a namespace to the root tag.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:xlink="URI">
    <link linkaction="immediate" linktype="return"
          xlink:href="IETM://S50005#S50005-TOOL1" xreftype="table">
        <prompt>Multimeter</prompt>
    </link>
    <link linkaction="immediate" linktype="return"
          xlink:href="IETM://S50005#S50018-TOOL15" xreftype="table">
        <prompt>Multimeter</prompt>
    </link>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="URI">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="link">
        <xref itemid="{substring-after(@xlink:href, '#')}" wpid="{substring-before(substring-after(@xlink:href, '#'),'-')}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<root xmlns:xlink="URI">
  <xref itemid="S50005-TOOL1" wpid="S50005" />
  <xref itemid="S50018-TOOL15" wpid="S50018" />
</root>
```